# YouTube-DL: How to extract cookies from Opera for age restricted videos?

Tags: download, cookies, youtube-dl

I've been using YouTube-DL in Windows for a while now. Unfortunately YouTube recently made some change that has caused it to stop working on age restricted videos. The docs say that you can tell it to use a cookies file to get around this, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have an old system with an old version of Windows. Because of this, I can only run older browsers and YouTube no longer works in my old versions of Firefox or Pal Moon. In fact, stupid Google won't even let me log in using those browsers. So, I'm forced to use an older version of Opera (which I hate!).

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to save the cookies to a file that YouTube-DL will accept. All of the extensions I've tried save the cookies to a JSON file, but YouTube-DL doesn't like that.

How do I get the cookies out of Opera and into a text files that YouTube-DL can use to download age restricted videos?

Comment: Windows 98 SE + KernelEx 4.2.1 + AutoPatcher 2007 June Full will let you run up to Firefox 10 ESR (!), Windows 2k will let you run 12 and XP/Vista will let 52 ESR (!). Still I have seen an extension named cookies.txt for dumping cookies into text file (for YouTube-dl) which will work on Firefox 52 ESR. XP and Vista are quite old these days, so you can use cookies.txt there. Don't know what to do for 98 (95, no Firefox, only Netscape/IE) and 2k. Not sure for Opera. If you have Windows 7 or + (Supports all firefox/opera!) then you can do easily.

Answer (score 0):

Even this site is a royal pain in the %$#@*&! ass to use! Once logged in, none of the reply options work and I can't even find a damn option to log out. I had to delete the cookies to get this text box to show up.

I have XP, but I don't like the newer versions of Firefox. The last time I tried to upgrade (admittedly a long time ago), I ran into problems and it screwed up my profile.

I have the last version of Pale Moon that supports XP. Unfortunately, since they went to a new extensions format, it seems that the net has been scrubbed of all extensions that worked with the older versions. Yes, you can supposedly download an archive of them, but they're in a special format to  be used by an extension on the newer browsers, which doesn't help me at all.

There are several extensions for Opera that claim to save cookies to a "text" file, but they all save in JSON format and that's apparently not what YouTube-DL is looking for.